# Create a pdf file with the content of a list in C#

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio, pdf

I am trying to create a pdf file with the content of a list.

**I created the list this way:**

```
            int arrayLength = obj.records.Count;
            List<string> outPutList = new List<string>();
            

            for (int i = 0; i<arrayLength; i++)
            {
                str = "";
                str = obj.records[i].datetime + "         " + obj.records[i].userName + "              " + obj.records[i].inTime + "               " + obj.records[i].outTime;
                outPutList.Add(str);
                Console.WriteLine(str);
```

**I found on internet some sample code in C# that normally allows me to create a pdf with the content I want:**

```
            Spire.Pdf.PdfDocument doc = new Spire.Pdf.PdfDocument();
            PdfPageBase page = doc.Pages.Add(PdfPageSize.A4);
            float y = 30;

            PdfBrush brush1 = PdfBrushes.Black;
            PdfTrueTypeFont font1 = new PdfTrueTypeFont(new System.Drawing.Font("Impact", 18f, FontStyle.Regular), true);
            PdfStringFormat format1 = new PdfStringFormat(PdfTextAlignment.Center);
            page.Canvas.DrawString("Rapport", font1, brush1, page.Canvas.ClientSize.Width / 2, y, format1);
            
            y = y + font1.MeasureString("Rapport", format1).Height;
            
            y = y + 5;

            
            PdfList list = new PdfList(str);
            
            PdfLayoutResult result = list.Draw(page, 1, y);
            
            y = result.Bounds.Bottom;

            doc.SaveToFile("List.pdf"); 
            doc.Close();
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("List.pdf");
```

It seems that is working, but the pdf only has the last line of the list I created and not the entire content.

Do you know what the problem might be? Why am I getting only the last line and not the whole content of the list?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: As far as i understand the code, you are overwriting your variable `str` everytime you iterate the for-loop. So the last line will be the content of the `str` variable which you pass through when you initialize an instance op the `PdfList`. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: The variable **str** is the content of my report. For exemple while I am doing the Console.Writeline(str) I have all my users that appears  on the display window. So, I thought that If I write this " PdfList list = new PdfList(str);" , then the pdf will contain all the information. Althoigh is contains only one user.

Comment: If you want all the content of what you assign to the variable `str`, you can use the operator `+=`.  When you use `=`, the old value will be replaced with the new value after this operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you overwrite the value of the `str` variable. What you want to do is the following: (I added an extra variable for you to understand the difference between the `=` and the `+=` operators):

```cs
int arrayLength = obj.records.Count;
List<string> outPutList = new List<string>();

// Add new variable as empty string
string content = "";

for (int i = 0; i<arrayLength; i++)
{
    // give str new value
    str = "";
    // give str new value again
    str = obj.records[i].datetime + "         " + obj.records[i].userName + "              " + obj.records[i].inTime + "               " + obj.records[i].outTime;
    outPutList.Add(str);
    Console.WriteLine(str);
    
    // append str to content variable with old en new value
    content += str;
```

Then you pass the `content` variable within the initialization of the `PdfList` instance:

```cs
// Pass content variable to PdfList
PdfList list = new PdfList(content);
```

For a more detailed explanation about this operators, please read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/addition-operator

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: Yes, thank you, it helped me. Now, I can see all the lines from the list. Thank you very much :)) But I still do not get why i need to create 2 diffenret values in order to it to work

Comment: It doesn't need two variables in order for it to work, I wanted to show you the difference between the `+=` operator and the `=` operator.

Comment: yes thank you, I have done several tests and I got it :)                                                                  Also, all the information is on the same line, do you know how can I have one element from the list per line? I have tried:  **PdfList list = new PdfList("\n"+ content);** but it didn't change anything